Deriving |⟩ magic states from |⟩?
Analogous to the $|T\rangle$ and $|CCZ\rangle$ magic states, one can define a $|C^n Z\rangle$ magic state. Is there any known quantification of the amount of magic of this state, and is there a way to transform $|C^n Z \rangle$ to many $|CCZ \rangle$ magic states? If so, what is the rate w.r.t. $n$?

The simplest thing you could possibly do is to turn one $|C^nZ\rangle$ state into $O(1/2^n)$ $|CCZ\rangle$ states by measuring out $n-3$ of the qubits and discarding if any of the measurement results are $|0\rangle$ instead of $|1\rangle$.
At the moment I can't think of anything better. It seems like there should be some way of doing a conversion that has cost $O(1/n)$ instead of $O(1/2^n)$, probably involving catalysis, but nothing came to mind for how to actually do it.
If the $|C^nZ\rangle$ state was somehow magically unfolded into a $W_{2^n}$ state via a binary-to-unary converter at no cost, then you could deterministically recover one CCZ state by using measurement based uncomputation to uncompute CSWAP gates folding it back into a $W_8$ state followed by performing $W_8 \rightarrow CCZ$ which is 1-to-1.
For an upper bound, stabilizer nullity probably shows the rate can't be more than $(n+1)/3$. So it's somehwere between $(n+1)/3$ and $4/2^n$. Wide margins.

Thanks! It's unfortunate that the bounds are so wide. What if I instead move the goalposts and say I can perform a FT $C^n Z$ gate? I wonder if I can somehow use this to perform $\Theta(n)$ $CCZ$ gates, with the idea of state catalysis also what I had in mind. Is it any clearer in that case?

@RohanMehta Being able to do the gate instead of having the state is much more flexible because there are no probabilistic corrections. So you can definitely get at least 1 CCZ per C^nZ in that case by having ancillas in the 1 state.
